# ImageMagick some cases seemed to fail open

Tags: display, png

1.) Failed to open image below:

```
$ display WAVES1.png
display: ../../magick/quantum.c:216: DestroyQuantumInfo: Assertion `quantum_info != (QuantumInfo *) NULL' failed.
Aborted
```

2.) This seems to ope without problems:

```
$ display Firefox_wallpaper.png
```

The 1st case I can open for example with the kolourpaint.
I could not know though if that image is corrupted somehow.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  Are you using default packaged version(s)?  (ie. does your `apt-cache policy` results match your release, or 3rd party etc)

Comment: the behavior is changed with later version

Comment: We don't know what OS & release you are using, thus cannot know what version is default, and what version(s) are available to you, so how is "*the behavior is changed with a later version*" helpful? given we don't know what you're running?